# Accessing the entire matrix (not he value of the current job) in a GitHub workflow step... impossible?

Tags: github, github-actions

```
jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: '${{ matrix.stage }}:${{ matrix.version }}'
        env:
            foo: bar
        strategy:
            fail-fast: false
            matrix:
                version: ["8.2", "8.1", "8.0", "7.4", "7.1"]
                stage: ['php-dev', 'php-prod']

    steps:
        - name: Debug
          run: |
            echo "${{ toJson(github) }}"
            echo "${{ toJson(env) }}"
            echo "${{ toJson(matrix) }}"
```

Even reading the documentation about [contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts), It seems I can't find a way to **access the entire matrix** (not the value of the current job!) inside my step.

I need the version array [`"8.2", "8.1", "8.0", "7.4", "7.1"]` defined in the strategy. I'v tried dumping `github`, `env`, `matrix` without luck. I don't believe that value isn't exposed, so I think I'm missing something from the documentation.

Comment: May be this https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26930 will give you some direction

Comment: You can use `yq` and `jq` directly with the workflow file e.g. `versions=$(yq -o=json '.jobs.build.strategy.matrix.version' workflow.yml | jq -c)`.